# CentOS 6 iptables nat router

Tags: linux, centos, router, nat

I'm attempting to setup a nat router for a lab to simulate a private network connected to a WAN. I have three virtual machines:

- public ip 192.168.0.5/24
- private ip 172.16.0.5/24
- router 192.168.0.1/24 (eth0), 172.16.0.1/24 (eth1)

I started by configuring each system's networking and confirmed I could ping from private->router and back and public->router and back.

Then I set `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to 1 using `sysctl.conf`, and applied the changes.
At this point I was unable to ping private to public and public to private. Flushing router's iptables rules fixed the problem.

```
iptables -F
iptables -t net -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle-X
```

Then following the guide for CENTOS6/RHEL6 I issued these iptables commands to setup forwarding

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The confusion begins. I am able to ping from private to public, using a tcp dump I can confirm the IP address is masquerading correctly. However I am also able to ping from public to private.

Here is a dump of linux router's `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

I've played around with adding rejects, input state related/established. I can't seem to keep the supposedly pubic host from peering into the private network. Any ideas? I'm sure I have something wrong.

Comment: Could the issue be having the public client which has an IP of 192.168.0.5 configured to use 192.168.0.1 as its gateway? In reality the Linux OS running the NAT shouldn't be used as anyone's gateway on the public network.

Comment: Nevermind, if a public host does try to use my Linux os as a gateway, I still have the problem of it coming in. Its still a security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!
First, flush iptables like before:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t net -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -X
```

Setup filter policies

```
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Then setup masquerading

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then setup a filter to prevent routing to your private interface. This keeps public hosts from using the router as a gateway. Without this I can ping the private interface of the router from public.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Finally, setup forwarding

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default policy for the filter table should be DROP, not ACCEPT, else you forward all packets by default.

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Comment: Running this makes no changes to the result. I can still ping through from the public address to the private.